# How to post JSON array of objects using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, shopify

I am using Javascript/jQuery in the Chrome browser console to post data to a page. (I'm doing this in Shopify admin, because it doesn't have the capability to bulk import shipping rates).

This is the code I am using:

```
make_weight_based_shipping_rate(8267845, 98, 99, 'Test Shipping Rate', 59);

function make_weight_based_shipping_rate(cid, minWeight, maxWeight, name, price) {
  $.post('/admin/weight_based_shipping_rates.json', {
    weight_based_shipping_rate: {
      country_id: cid,
      name: name,
      offsets: [{disabled:true, offset:0, province_id:145570341}, {disabled:true, offset:0, province_id:145570345}], 
      weight_high: maxWeight,
      weight_low: minWeight,
      price: price
    }
  });
}
```

It works well, except for one line of my request which has an array of objects - the line that begins with 'offsets'.

If I only have one JSON object on this line, and not in an array (by excluding the square brackets), this code works. However, as an array, Shopify comes back with the error '422 (Unprocessable Entity)' and in the body of the response it says '{"errors":{"shipping_rate_offsets":["is invalid"]}}'.

Am I formatting this JSON object incorrectly? If not, is there some other way I can achieve this rather than use the JQuery Post method?

Comment: Your javascript (not JSON) looks fine. Unfortunately this looks like an issue with the way Shopify handles that field - presumably the service provides some sort of support? You'd get a much more accurate answer there.

Comment: Thanks RGraham - this is a workaround that I saw someone else describe. I'm not really sure if Shopify appreciate people doing this kind of thing - it's not part of their official API.

Comment: I saw your post [here](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/payments-shipping-fulfilment/t/bulk-import-shipping-options-134653). Looks like the guys posted that code publicly, so I'd say they're fairly open to supporting it :)

Comment: Also, I asked one of their support staff a question about the API and they said to post it here..!

Comment: Nice use of Google :) I'm hoping they will answer, but thought StackOverflow would have a wider reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. By default, JQuery POST and AJAX requests are encoded as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". This works most of the time, but it seems to fail when it gets an array such as 'offsets'.

To get around this, first I had to use the JSON.stringify() function on the data being submitted. Then prior to making the POST, I used the ajaxSetup() function to set the content-type to "application/json". My modified code is now:

```
make_weight_based_shipping_rate(8267845, 98, 99, 'Test Shipping Rate', 59);

function make_weight_based_shipping_rate(cid, minWeight, maxWeight, name, price) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
  $.post('/admin/weight_based_shipping_rates.json', JSON.stringify({
    weight_based_shipping_rate: {
      country_id: cid,
      name: name,
      offsets: [{disabled:true, offset:0, province_id:145570341}, {disabled:true, offset:0.00, province_id:145570345}], 
      weight_high: maxWeight,
      weight_low: minWeight,
      price: price
    }
  }));
}
```

I hope this helps others.